# How can I tell to my prepare method on which cell a button has been pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I added a button  `@IBOutlet weak var cellButton: UIButton!` in my custom `tableViewCell` class and an action of the button in my `tableView` controller

```
 @IBAction func cellButtonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {

      performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMap" , sender: self)

    }
```

what I need to do is to pass data to another viewController but is important to know on which cell the button has been pressed, so how can I tell my method prepare

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "goToMap"...//HERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO

}
```

on which cell the button has been pressed? I'm a beginner and I've been looking for a solution for two days but I have not found it yet

Comment: Just set tag of your cell and when you press cell check the tag of cell to know which cell is being pressed

Comment: Use a protocol in your custom cell.  Here is an example: https://medium.com/@aapierce0/swift-using-protocols-to-add-custom-behavior-to-a-uitableviewcell-2c1f09610aa1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a "call back" closure...

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var didButtonTapAction : (()->())?

    @IBAction func cellButtonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // call back closure
        didButtonTapAction()?
    }

}
```

in your table view controller, add a class-level variable:

```
var tappedIndexPath: IndexPath?
```

and then your table view cell setup becomes:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

    // set labels, colors, etc in your cell

    // set a "call back" closure
    cell.didButtonTapAction = {
        () in
        print("Button was tapped in cell at:", indexPath)

        // you now have the indexPath of the cell containing the
        // button that was tapped, so
        // call performSegue() or do something else...

        self.tappedIndexPath = indexPath
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMap" , sender: self)
    }

    return cell
}
```

and, in prepare:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "goToMap" {
         // do what you need based on the row / section
         // of the cell that had the button that was tapped, such as:

        if let vc = segue.destination as? MyMapViewController {
              vc.myData = self.dataArray[self.tappedIndexPath.row]
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: ah ok so in my prepare i only need to write  if segue.identifier == "goToMap"{ }  and it already consider on which cell was the button ?

Comment: I edited the answer... should get you on your way.

Comment: great answer thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you need a button at all? Normally it is happened through table view selection delegate.
2. If you need a button, you need to provide a way to identify what button was pressed. If you have simple one-dimensional array of items to present, simplest method is to setup button's `tag` to index

Like:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "<id>", for: indexPath) as? Cell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
        //...
        return cell
    }
```

then it will better to trigger segue with button as sender:

```
 @IBAction func cellButtonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMap" , sender: sender)
 }
```

And you can get you data:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToMap", let index = (sender as? UIView)?.tag {

        }

}
```

Comment: Using a tag to represent an index path is a poor choice. If the table view allows for rows to be deleted, inserted, or moved, the tag will be wrong.

Comment: As I said it works in simplest cases. Similar limitations can be with any "button in the cell" solutions, such as blocks, etc.

Comment: No, proper solutions do not have limitations.

Comment: It is philosophical question. You can always imagine the edge-case when when previous reasonable solution stop working. But usually good developer  estimate how his solution going to be used and use simplest approach.